# Why does Enumerable#to_a behave this way in Ruby versions >= 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby

Is this a bug in MRI or is there a good explanation for this behavior?

```
def pmap(enum)
  return to_enum(:pmap, enum) unless block_given?
  enum.map { |e| Thread.new { yield e } }.map(&:value)
end

# Returns elements in order, as expected.
pmap(1..10) { |e| e } #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Returns elements in nondeterministic order on MRI >= 1.9.3.
# Works as expected on JRuby, Rubinius, and earlier versions of MRI.
pmap(1..10).to_a      #=> [7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 9, 8, 10, 1]
```

The first `map` should return an array of threads, with the first thread yielding `1`, etc.

The second `map` should collect the values of each of those threads.

I don’t understand why the results would come back out-of-order.

I’ve looked at [what I believe is the relevant code in `enum.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/db17d694ea6849b813a09856008310168c5a04ea/enum.c#L488-L510), but I still don’t understand why this is happening. I suspect it’s a performance optimization gone wrong. Or am I expecting too much of `Enumerable#to_a` (specifically, that it doesn’t change the ordering of the enumerable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[line 3](https://gist.github.com/sferik/9284252#file-pmap-rb-L3) maps the enumeration to threads returning immediately and independent of the completion of the thread's block.  `.value` [blocks on the completion of the thread](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Thread.html#method-i-value) long after it was created.

This shows that the actual evaluation of the Thread's block doesn't occur *in order*, but the results of the Thread.new initialization do occur fast enough to result in orderly Thread instances.

```
def pmap(enum)
  return to_enum(:pmap, enum) unless block_given?
  enum.map { |e| Thread.new { sleep(Random.rand); p e; yield e } }.map(&:value) 
end

pmap(1..10) { |e| e } 

1  
2  
5  
6  
8  
3  
7  
9  
4  
10
```

Here is how you can order the results of a parallel execution via `to_enum` which uses fibers to execute the block:

```
def pmap(enum)
  return to_enum(:pmap, enum) unless block_given?
  enum.each_with_index.map { |e,i| Thread.new { sleep(Random.rand); p e; yield ({index: i, value:e }) } }.map(&:value)
end

p to_enum(:pmap, 1..10).sort_by { |hash| hash[:index] }.map { |hash| hash[:value] }
#p pmap(1..10) { |x| x }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are yielding from thread, and as threads are executed concurrently there is a good chance that they yield in an arbitrary order. And my guess is that enumerator is using a sequence of `yield` calls to form output. 1.9.3 use OS threads while 1.8.7 has "green" threads which may explain the difference.

Comment: Nope. This doesn’t fix it.

Comment: Edited my answer, didn't realize at first you were trying to `yield` from thread, IMO it's not a good idea.